# Request Limits on web-services and api-key

Tags: android, web-services, api-key

I am creating an android application which call an web-service and parses the response (json). The web-service requires an api-key and also there are limits put on requests per day.

My question is:-

1. When a user downloads my android app should he/she use my api-key or should there be a separate api-key for each user ?
2. If the user uses my api-key, how to control the number of api request so that I don't exceed the limit ?

Comment: this is what I can think of. 
1. If there are separate api-key for each user you can enforce the limit in you r app. 
2. If user uses your api-key, I think you need to have a service to keep track of your api-key usage and enforce the limit